# Executable not running even after chmod'ing it

Tags: executable, chmod

I am trying to run a BETA precompiled copy of rcracki, but the problem is when I try to run the executable, it gives an error:

```
root@hosted-by:~/Desktop/rcracki_mt_0.7_beta2_linux_x86_64# ls
COPYING             INSTALLING.txt  charset.txt    libcudart.so.2
libstdc++.so.6      rcracki_mt.ini  ChangeLog.txt  README.txt
libcrypto.so.0.9.8  libgcc_s.so.1   rcracki_mt

root@hosted-by:~/Desktop/rcracki_mt_0.7_beta2_linux_x86_64# sudo chmod +rwx cracki_mt

root@hosted-by:~/Desktop/rcracki_mt_0.7_beta2_linux_x86_64# ./rcracki_mt
bash: ./rcracki_mt: No such file or directory`

root@hosted-by:~/Desktop/rcracki_mt_0.7_beta2_linux_x86_64# sudo ./rcracki_mt`
sudo: unable to execute ./rcracki_mt: No such file or directory
```

So does anyone have a clue as to why Ubuntu gives this error? I mean the file is right here, so the error doesn't make sense!

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: what do you get when you ls -ltr?

Comment: The file you've been trying to run is either not there or is named differently, or, perhaps the file system is a non-linux one. When typing commands as root, there is no need to use `sudo`, also, to make something executable, `chmod +x` is enough, no need to fire all the cannons.

Comment: Output for `ls -ltr` is shown here: http://i.imgur.com/LxOr3.png .. and I know about not using sudo and only using +x for chmod .. I just did these extra things to see if anything makes any difference ... Also, as the `ls -ltr` output shows, the file is very much there ..

Comment: Here is another `ls -ltr` image, which shows me trying to run the executable right after its seen as listed via `ls -ltr`: http://i.imgur.com/aPi9y.png  ... So the file is 100% there, and yet still Ubuntu isn't executing it for some reason ..

Comment: What is the output of "file rcracki_mt"? Assuming that doesn't say the file isn't there, what's the output of "file ./rcracki_mt"? Perhaps there is a subtle problem in your environment causing the relative indicator . to be interpreted incorrectly some or all of the time.

Comment: Here you go, outputs of both commands: http://i.imgur.com/rNsHf.png ... Does it help in solving the mystery ?

Comment: when you type  ls -ltr ./r then press tab a few times before pressing enter do you get shown one file or several?

Comment: When pressing tab like this, rcracki_mt is always filled in for me, meaning that the OS detects the executable and fills its name in for me .. If I press tab a few times for the command you suggested, two files get listed: rcracki_mt and rcracki_mt.ini ..

Comment: Are all the libraries the executable needs present? Try `ldd rcraki_mt`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/297151/how-to-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-system

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my 64-bit machine when I downloaded file for 32-bit platform.
Unfortunately you don´t see any error message if you try to execute such a file.

Check your file type using **file** command e.g.:

#### 32-bit

```
N56VZ:~$ file /opt/eclipse/eclipse
eclipse: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped
```

#### 64-bit

```
N56VZ:~$ file /opt/eclipse/eclipse
eclipse: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped
```

Comment: Yeah, this is likely the problem. The error message comes from the kernel, which tries to run the 32-bit library loader in order to run the 32-bit binary, but the 32-bit library loader doesn't exist. The shell just relays that error message. The fix is to install the ia32-libs package.