# How to install 32-bit Matlab in Ubuntu 64-bit?

Tags: software-installation, matlab

While running previous versions of Ubuntu (prior to 13.10) I was able to follow the instructions listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB) to install 32-bit Matlab while running 64-bit Ubuntu. Now in 13.10 I am no longer able to install the `ia32-libs` package which contains several dependencies that Matlab uses. Matlab uses a Java installer so `dpkg` is no help.

How do I meet these dependencies in Ubuntu 13.10 and later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I got it to work was to follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB). After running the command:

```
sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install -glnx86 -v
```

if there are unmet dependencies it will complain about some library not found. Next, [search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) for this library in Ubuntu's packages for your release (in this case saucy). Make sure to search the contents of the packages. After you find the package name, install it: (make sure to include the trailing `:i386`)

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>:i386
```

**For example:**

I am using the Student version of 2011a and the required packages for me on Ubuntu 13.10 are:

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386 libXext6:i386 libxi6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libxt6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxp6:i386
```

**Edit:**

For installing the Student version of 2011a on Xubuntu 14.04 I had to also install the `lib32stdc++6` package:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install MATLAB R2013a CYGiSO for windows 32bit. But you must use WINE tool.

Extract `matlabR2013aCYGiSO.iso` files in one of the ubunut directories. Then run setup.exe using WINE. If you have WINE installed just double click on setup.exe. When MATLAB has installed, go to Home directory.

Edit->Preferences(select Show hidden and backup files).

Then go to directory "Home->.wine ->drive_c->Program Files->MATLAB->R2013a->bin->(double click on matlab.exe)".

When opened ->Choose license.dat in CYGiSO directory.

Now you can run matlab.exe.