# Ubuntu 13.10 64bit non-apt program needs 32bit functionality how?

Tags: software-installation

[What happened to the ia32-libs package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package)

So I've been reading through several answers about the ia32-libs package being no longer supported, which is cool. However, I have a somewhat unique circumstance. On my workstation at work, I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on an AMD64, and I need to run Liveperson, which requires Java 6, and 32-bitness. It's also not available through apt, and has to be installed independently.

While I was running 12.04, there were ways to still get the ia32-libs package, which was necessary. Is there a way to make this work on 13.10?

Comment: i have installed ia32-libs .. and its working on 13.04 .. actually its just providing libs of 32 to 64 ... try that..

Comment: hmm. How did you install ia32-libs? I used:

$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

and got an error (i.e. the 'this no longer exists' error). Sorry if that sounds simplistic and like I'm not trying to work for this or anything, I'm not really good at super user-ing yet lol.

Comment: Sorry then , i think its for the versions before then 13.10

Answer (score 1):

ia32-libs has been removed completely. The way to install i386 libraries now is one at a time as you need them. This isn't a problem for applications from the repo since it will just automatically install what you need, but installing from a .deb is problematic.

This will cover the method to discover and install the dependencies you need: [How do you run a 32-bit program on a 64-bit version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to install 32-bit Matlab (which is also non-apt and Java based) on a machine running 13.10 64-bit (see question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363878/how-to-install-32-bit-matlab-in-ubuntu-64-bit)).

Try installing Liveperson as you have done in the past except without installing `ia32-libs`. ***Hopefully*** if there are unmet dependencies it will complain about some library not found. Next, [search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) for this library in Ubuntu's packages for your release (in this case saucy). Make sure to search the contents of the packages. After you find the package name, install it: (make sure to include the trailing `:i386`)

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>:i386
```

Next, try to install Liveperson again. Repeat this process until all dependencies are met.

**As an example:** I am using the Student version of Matlab 2011a and the required packages for me on Ubuntu 13.10 are:

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386 libXext6:i386 libxi6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libxt6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxp6:i386
```