# 32bit program on 64bit Ubuntu fails when using linux 32 before setup.sh

Tags: command-line, 64-bit, 32-bit

When I try to install a 32 bit program on ubuntu 13.10 64bit it falis. My command is as follow:

```
linux32 ./setup.sh
```

Output is:

```
The setup program seems to have failed on x86/unknown

Fatal error, no tech support email configured in this setup
```

Is there a way to install 32bit program on ubuntu 13.10?
When running the following command:

```
./setup.sh
```

The output is as below:

```
The setup program seems to have failed on amd64/unknown

Fatal error, no tech support email configured in this setup
```

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297151/how-to-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-system-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: @wilf Didn't help. I get `ia32-libs has no candidate` error.

Comment: @phpGeek What is the output of `uname -a` and what 32bit program are you trying to `./setup.sh` ?

Comment: I want to install Longman Dictionary.

Comment: Output:  Linux myUserName 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You could also try `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`

Comment: I think the problem is as @Wilf has pointed out and that you do not have the 32bit architecture support needed to install a 32bit program on a 64bit system. Run the command he suggested, then try installing again and see what happens

Comment: I installed what @Wilf said, and it everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```