# Run an executable file

Tags: chmod

I have changed file permission_mode,but I can not run
 any executable file.

```
ls -li
chmod a+x file_name
./file_name
sudo ./file_name
```

Comment: What is the content of file_name ?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `namei -lx ./file_name`

Comment: there is noa ny output..after fire that command to run.

Answer (score 1):

Possible things that can prevent execution of files are:

1. Security modules
2. mount options
3. binary files for a different architecture

**[Security modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules)**

Things like AppArmor or SELinux can prevent executables from paths. This would be logged in the system logs I guess.

**[Mount options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Options)**

Determine the filesystem where the binary is stored (I use `df -T ./file_name` and use the first column) and check `mount | grep /dev/md2` to see if the noexec option is included

**Architecture incompability**

I use `ldd ts3server_linux_x86` which might respond with

```
        not a dynamic executable
```

when the file isn't compatible with your system. My shell would respond with

```
zsh: no such file or directory: ./ts3server_linux_x86
```

if I try to execute a incompatible binary. Also like in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73619/executable-not-running-even-after-chmoding-it?rq=1) you can check with `file ./file_name` what architecture the binary was created at.

Comment: i got like this:.................

Comment: df -T ./msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-4.2.0.36.run 
Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      ext4  35845768 3258712  30743140  10% /home

Comment: mount|grep/dev/sda6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           /dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

Comment: for architecture check..............                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ldd msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-4.2.0.36.run_linux_x86
ldd: ./msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-4.2.0.36.run_linux_x86: No such file or directory

Comment: when i check threw file command.....................                                                                                                                                                      file /home/kishan/dash7/msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-4.2.0.36.run 
/home/kishan/dash7/msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-4.2.0.36.run: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped
...............................

Comment: actually i forgot to told that i can execute a.out files,but problem occurs for .run , .bin,..etc files..

Comment: when i use ldd.......... command                            ..............                                                                       ldd msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-4.2.0.36.run 
 not a dynamic executable

Comment: thanks for giving solution........finally i have done it after updating and upgrading.......................

Answer (score 0):

If the output of `./file_name` in a shell is empty (i. e. no error messages) then it was executed successfully. The program just happened to not produce any data on stdout or stderr.