# How can I run an executable file named "c2p.i696"

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 20.04, wine, execute-command

I am trying to run a file name `c2p.i686`. This is an executable file, but I don't know how to execute this file.

[image: file shown in terminal screenshot - ls color shows it's executable]

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/854531/run-an-executable-file

Answer (score 0):

If it an exe, and it is for your architecture (i686), a simple `chmod +x [file]` in terminal and then `./[file]` will execute the file.